# What's a good translation for "Et encore,..."

Tags: traduction

I wonder if there's a good translation in English for the phrase "et encore,...".
It is a very common French phrase used mostly in "[This bad thing happened] et encore [if it hadn't been for this other thing, it would have worse]

> Il a dû payer 200 euros de réparations de voiture, et encore, il a eu une remise.
> He had to pay 200 euros to repair his car, [et encore] he had a discount
>
> Elle est arrivée vingt minutes en retard, et encore, elle a trouvé tout de suite la salle de réunion.
> She arrived twenty minutes late [et encore] she found the meeting room straight away

It is maybe not very formal.

Comment: I would say "and even then", but I think it's a question more fitted for the English SO : http://english.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: A very common French phrase. Fyi, we don't say locution. Le CNTRL dit ceci: [Encore, marque de l'affirmation sous réserve; et encore! corrige l'énoncé précédent en indiquant avec une certaine véhémence, qu'après réflexion, on constate qu'il n'est conforme à la vérité que jusqu'à un certain point (ce que justifie gén. la suite du discours). That is one use. Is that the one you mean in the two sentences? However, your first would be: A bad thing happened and it could have been worse. Et encore at the end.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the mistakes you pointed out in my question, I will edit it !
Does the english.stackexchange.com handle such translation questions ?

Comment: I think the definition you propose is close to what I mean even if it's not exactly it. In my examples sentences, there's not really the idea of "'après réflexion, on constate qu'il n'est conforme à la vérité que jusqu'à un certain point". The first part of the sentence is completely true, not "jusqu'à un certain point".

Comment: For me, et encore in the two sentences with the yellow background (not the first one), would be: even so. Though even so doesn't go so well with the first one. She was 20 minutes late and even so, she still found the room.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't "even so" means "[thing 1 happens which makes thing 2 difficult to do] and even so [thing 2 happens]", doesn't it ? This is not really what the 2 sentences mean. The room example means "she immediately found the room, and still was 20 minutes late" meaning "she would have been even later if she hand't found the room right away"

Comment: In your two examples, I'd take it to mean "even though" ...."He had to pay 200 euros to repair his car,  **even though** he had a discount."    "She arrived twenty minutes late, **even though** she found the meeting room straight away."

Comment: I dunno, I find the first sentence to be odd. He had to pay 200 euros, and even so, he had a discount. (that is why ***I find it odd, in French and in English***!) ***Even though*** for me would be: Il a dû payer 200 euros ***malgré*** (even though he got) une remise.

Comment: And we can say in English: She arrived 20 minutes late. Even so, she found the meeting room straight away.

Comment: @PapaPoule, I think we are getting close grammatically. However, "even though" is sort of this broad term, and does not convey the "véhémence" Lambie was talking about. I think "even though" would suit sentences like "Il a payé 200 euros malgré une remise." ou "Il a payé 200 euros même avec une remise.", which are more "neutral-toned" than the "et encore" ones which add a bit more drama. But it's pretty close !

Comment: Yes, @Lambie, I think we are not understanding each other. I do *not* mean ."He had to pay 200 euros, and even so, he had a discount.". I mean "He had to pay 200 euros, which is already a lot, and it would have been even worse if he hadn't had that discount."

Comment: Even so can be et encore. Ils ont travaillé beacoup, et encore ils se sont amusés. They worked at lot. Even so, they amused themselves.

Comment: @Lambie I never used "et encore" in something like "Ils ont travaillé beacoup, et encore ils se sont amusés". Maybe it exists but I don't mean it that way

Comment: He had to pay 200 euros and even had a discount.

Comment: OK, I'm out. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems OP is asking for the correctness of a sentence in English, so it should be asked on English Language and Usage, not French Language.

Comment: Perhaps the notion of “sans oublier” or “et n'oublie/z pas” is what is meant by “Et encore” in your examples (= "**and don't forget that** he had a discount" &/or "**and keep in mind that** she found the meeting room straight away"), which would, imo, make them less neutral (albeit, well short of being vehemently so). ... To try to avoid getting your question closed, maybe you could edit and ask instead for French alternatives to “Et encore” as it’s used in your examples and from there do your own translating of any alternatives that you might get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general sens of *"et encore"* in a sentence is to mark opposition in an "ironic way" to the general idea of the text. In your example:

> Il a dû payer 200 euros de réparations de voiture, et encore, il a eu une remise.

The general idea is **high cost of repairs** (200 euros), but *"et encore"* marks opposition to this idea (remise=discount). So if I'm asked to translate your example I say:

> He had to pay 200 euros to repair his car, in spite of the discount

To my knowledge, "in spite of" marks here the opposition in question.

Your second example describes the same principle of *"et encore"* use.

Comment: Sorry, but /despite he had a discount/  is not grammatical in English. Did you mean: /and despite that he still got a discount/?

Comment: Yes, it's what I mean since it marks "opposition".

Comment: That would be /even so/.

Comment: I think "even so" is better, I will edit my answer with your "even so" suggestion